# How to use mysql "IN" clause when using place holder in PDO object?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can someone tell the place holder code to write when using mysql 'in' clause.This is sample code. I am using where 1=1 because there are more than one(dynamic) where conditions which I have not included in the below code.

```
<?php
$PDOconn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobportal","root","");

if(isset($_GET["btnSubmit"])) {
    $qualifs = "";
    foreach($_GET["list_qualif"] as $qualif) {
        if($qualifs == ""){
            $qualifs = $qualif;
        } else {
            $qualifs .= ",".$qualif;
        }
    }
    $where = "1 = 1 "

    if(!empty($qualifs)) {
        $where = $where."AND qualification IN :qualifs";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_info WHERE $where ";
    $stmt = $PDOconn->prepare($sql) or die($PDOconn->error);

    if(!empty($qualifs)) {
        $qualificationFormat = "(".$qualifs.")";
        $stmt->bindParam(":qualifs",$qualificationFormat);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    if($result[0] > 0) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE $where ";
        $stmt = $PDOconn->prepare($sql) or die($PDOconn->error);
        if(!empty($qualifs)) {
            $qualificationFormat = "(".$qualifs.")";
            $stmt->bindParam(":qualifs",$qualificationFormat);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        // if there is no matching rows do following
        $msg = "No results";
    }
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($result) && $result[0] > 0) {
    while($row1 = $stmt->fetch()) { 
?>
        <div class='col-md-2'><?php echo $row1[14];?></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'><?php $row1[1];?></div>
    <?php 
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="list_qualif[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%;"> 
        <option value="M.C.A.">M.C.A.</option>
        <option value="B.C.A">B.C.A.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: downvote for the most horribly formatted code

Comment: Sorry for my hasty mess. Please see now I have corrected the problem.